# Доступ к ресурсам из Fragment

Tags: android-fragment, android, resources

Есть Fragment, в который передается Id строкового ресурса. Надо прочитать из него строку. Закомментированы разные варианты использования, найденные на просторах Интернета, но ни один не работает, приложение вылетает по ошибке.

```
public class SimpleDialog extends DialogFragment implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

public SimpleDialog setDialog(int messageId, int mode) {
    message = getResources().getString(messageId);
//        message = getString(messageId);  
//        message = getApplication.getString(messageId);
//        message = Resources.getSystem().getString(messageId);
    this.mode = mode;
    return this;
}
```

Вызов происходит отсюда:

```
public void onButtonClick(View v) {
    SimpleDialog dlg = new SimpleDialog();
    dlg.setDialog(R.string.message, SimpleDialog.OK_CANCEL).show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dlg_1");
}
```

Заменяю код на такой - и все работает, но хочется, чтобы чтение ресурсов происходило внутри диалога:

```
public SimpleDialog setDialog(String message, int mode) {
this.message = message;
this.mode = mode;
return this;
}

    public void onButtonClick(View v) {
        SimpleDialog dlg = new SimpleDialog();
        dlg.setDialog(getString(R.string.message), SimpleDialog.OK_CANCEL).show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dlg_1");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> приложение вылетает по ошибке

А вот если бы вы прочитали эту ошибку, точнее, её стэктрейс, то увидели бы, что вы получаете `IllegalStateException` с текстом "Fragment not attached to Activity". То есть проблема в том, что фрагменту на момент вызова `setDialog(…)` не назначена владеющая им `Activity`.

Поэтому и все вызовы `getString()`, `getResources()` и прочие, фактически, являющиеся лишь алиасами к `getActivity().getString()`, `getActivity().getResources()`, заканчиваются неудачей.

А причина всего этого проста — вы неверно используете фрагменты, неверно понимаете их механику работы и, как следствие, механику их инициализации. Посмотрите, например, сэмплы из поставки SDK. Они хорошо раскрывают эту тему.

В сложившейся же ситуации вам нужно либо вызывать `setDialog()` после вызова `show()` у фрагмента, либо передавать в `setDialog()` одним из аргументов `Context`. Но лучше всего, сделать фабричный метод, где передавать фрагменту аргументы посредством `setArguments()`, а внутри `onCreateDialog` извлекать их при помощи `getArguments()`. На этом этапе фрагмент уже будет в `attached state`, и вы сможете спокойно использовать `getString()`, `getResources()` и прочие схожие методы.

А вообще, внутри вашего `DialogFragment`'а вы, скорее всего, используете `AlertDialog.Builder`. Его методы `setTitle()` и `setMessage()` могут принимать также и идентификаторы строковых ресурсов.

Comment: Спасибо, все понял!

Comment: Рад был помочь.

Answer (score 1):

Во фрагментах доступен метод же `getString(resId)`.

Правильно, нужно в `onCreateDialog()` это делать или в `onCreateView()`.

Comment: `getResources()` и основанный на нём `getString()` будут кидать `IllegalStateException`, пока фрагмент находится в `detached state`. Здесь как раз такой случай.

Comment: Правильно, нужно в onCreateDialog() это делать или в onCreateView().